# Why is ID after the assignment in the loop 0?

Tags: go

I am trying to create a array of struct and initiate some data in it.

The struct:

```
type Person struct{
    id int
    enlighten bool
    channel chan int
}
```

The assignments:

```
table := make([]Philospher, numPhil)
for i :=0; i < 5; i++{
    p  := Philospher{
        id: i,
        enlighten: false,
        channel: make(chan int),
    }
    table = append(table, p)
}

for j :=0; j < 5; j++{
    fmt.Println(table[j].id);
}
```

The following are the output of above code:

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

I am trying to figure out why it is not

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

I have also tried to use add `&` in front of Philospher, and  it is the same thing

Any help is appreciated

Comment: "I have also tried to use add & in front of Philospher, and it is the same thing" as expected. If you don't know what something does, don't use it. If you would like to know what "adding & in front" does, it's covered in the Tour: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `make` call is creating a Philosopher slice with the initial length of 5. From the spec:

> A new, initialized slice value for a given element type T is made using the built-in function `make`, which takes a slice type and parameters specifying the length and optionally the capacity. A slice created with make always allocates a new, hidden array to which the returned slice value refers. That is, executing
>
> ```
> make([]T, length, capacity)
> ```

Those first 5 Philosophers are the zero value of Philosopher. You append 5 more Philosophers to the end of the slice which gives it a [final length of 10](https://play.golang.org/p/xIwqaz8RdSa). What I believe you meant to do is create a slice with the length of 0 but a capacity of 5:

```
table := make([]Philosopher, 0, numPhil)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/a5QP6wd6Rs_9

Answer (score 2):

Because of this:

```
table := make([]Philospher, numPhil)
```

This creates `table` with `numPhil` empty elements. Then you add your `Philosohper`s to the end of this empty table, and print of the first 5. Apparently, `numPhil >= 5`, so it prints out the first empty ones.

Change the initialization to:

```
table:= make([]Philosopher,0,numPhil)
```

to reserve space for numPhil elements, with a size of 0.